# SeekBar with translucent thumb overlapping

Tags: android, opacity, android-seekbar

My tinted translucent `SeekBar` is rendering differently in API 25 as in API 21.

**code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/md_green_500"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="16dp">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="10"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:progressTint="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
        android:thumbTint="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGrrZ.png)

From left:

1. API 21
2. API 21, `android:splitTrack="false"`
3. API 25
4. API 25, `android:splitTrack="false"`

---

**What I'm trying to do:**

- I want the third `SeekBar` to be the same as the first - the progress bar should end at the start of the thumb, not somewhere below it
- Ideally i want to be able to use [`PorterDuff.Mode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html)'s Alpha compositing modes. (Destination Over)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem quite differently.

1. I set all the tint to **black**:

   ```
       android:progressTint="@android:color/black"
       android:thumbTint="@android:color/black"
   ```
2. I added the **opacity attribute** and set the value to `0.54` ([secondary text opacity](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0BxFyKV4eeNjDa0dlWGxkWXBnTUk/style_color_usability_alpha1_161116.png))

   ```
       android:alpha="0.54"
   ```

And finally [it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvnbj.png)! :)